# Does Google's search algorithm really respect order of relevance imposed by PageRank?

Tags: information-retrieval

I'm in doubt about that because in Google's results for a search on "bill clinton" [1],
the server "The 'Unofficial' Bill Clinton" (94.06%) appears first than the server "President Bill Clinton - The Dark Side" (97.27%) and there is no feedback mechanism modifing the ranks.

Since I've noticed that, I am wondering if google uses some algorithm for efficiently intesecting inverted indices that exploits the PageRank although not completely preserving order.

[1] The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

Comment: What are the percentages 94.06% and 97.27% representing?  Where did you get them from?  Note that Google's search results differ for different people.  I don't see "The Unofficial Bill Clinton" or "President Bill Clinton - The Dark Side" anywhere among the first 10 search results for me, whether logged into my Google account or not, so I can't replicate this.  Finally, no one knows exactly what Google does internally -- unless someone at Google happens to have spoken about it, that's probably non-public information.  As it stands, this question might not be answerable.

Comment: Also, it's not clear that this question is on-topic.  Why is this computer science?  Asking about the internal details of exactly how some web site works is not computer science and probably not the kind of question we want to encourage here.  We want answerable technical questions about computer science (but not so much asking for an explanation of how individual businesses work, as that's not really science).

Comment: First: Sergey Brin and Lawrence Page represented PageRanks as percentages, 19 years ago. Those data are taken from the famous paper introducing the principles behind Google.

Comment: Second: Obviously I am speaking of a "non-public information" but there are some tips about what happens at Google. Read at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393781/how-do-search-engines-merge-results-from-an-inverted-index. More specific: "Actually search engines do merge these document lists" and "but I talked to its developers and was surprised to know that query execution algorithms are actually fairly dumb"

Comment: Third: PageRank (dominant eigenvalue of a transition matrix) is related to a Weighted Laplacian Matrix. The Spectrum of a Laplacian Matrix that can be exploited to make search algorithms and is related to some topics less studied, like Space-filling Curves. This is Computer Science! and not merely business.

Comment: I am trying to use PageRank to make search algorithms and not only for ranking. I hope to find someone with the same intentions. Have I answered the question:  Why is this computer science ?

Comment: I am familiar with the mathematics behind PageRank, and those are computer science -- but what Google does internally?  Not so sure that it's computer science.  On the other hand, a question about how to use PageRank for your application might be more suitable than asking what Google does -- it sounds more "answerable".  Just my take.  Others may have a different perspective.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat and the operations (merge, set intersection ... ) on inverted indices are computer science, which is done internally

Comment: there is a LOT in the search results that are not contained in that paper, because much of this is a trade secret, and theres a lot used to prevent spam, and documenting it means "gaming the system". it also is personalized based on individual users. it rejects blocked sites. etc. it has significantly evolved over more than a decade. you can learn about some of these changes studying search engine optimization. feel this question deserves more votes than 1v currently. there is probably some scientific study of google results, may look it up if this decent question can scrounge more interest.